# Errors installing php5-mysql extension

Tags: mysql, php

Getting error when installing php5-mysql. Looks like a dpkg error. Perhaps a broken package.

Have tried to fix the broken package.
Have reinstalled the lamp server and everything seems fine except being able to install the php5-mysql extension, I get:

```
Errors were encountered while processing: php5-mysql  

The sub-process for dpkg is returning an error code.
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Please give us the *complete* error.

Comment: Please give us a more comprehensive log of the error.

Answer (score 1):

This technique is based on [owl's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do), but:

- It avoids deleting the `.prerm` file. This file is needed to ensure the package is uninstalled cleanly, and removing it could potentially leave traces of the package remaining, leave the system configured in a way that expects the package to be installed, or *leave services provided by the package running, even once the files are removed*.

  That makes this technique safer, though potentially it might not work if there is *also* a problem running the `.prerm` script. (This may have been why owl said to delete it.) Fortunately, usually the `.prerm` script does not fail.
- This technique potentially removes more configuration files, so depending on the cause of the problem, this *might* be more effective.

  It also makes sure we are fetching the correct version of the package to install.

Run:

```
sudo dpkg -P php5-mysql
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

If there are no errors, then everything is cleaned up from the previous installation and `php5-mysql` is installed. In that case, the package should work properly now.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try this command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/php5-mysqlnd.prerm
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get autoremove php5-mysql
```

This allowed me to install `php5-mysql` again.

So install php5-mysql again:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: This is really not a good idea.

Comment: Why not? I think it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I ended up deleting all the package files relative to mysql and was able to reinstall.

Comment: @DarylWood In that case, you should mark this as the accepted answer, by clicking the gray check mark to the left of it.